# Kendo ui datasource: Object doesn't support property or method '_observe'

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 page that use Kendo ui autocomplete widget to retrieve some JSON information from the server.

```
@{
  Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var autocompleteDataSource = kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
          transport:
            read: {
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json",
              url: "/",
              data: {
                address: function() {
                  return $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
                }
              },
              dataType: "json"
            }
          },
          schema: {
            data: function (response) {
              return response.data;
            }
          }
        });

        $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
          minLength: 2,
          dataSource: autocompleteDataSource,
          change: function () {
            this.dataSource.read();
          }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I execute this code, I get this error in kendo.web.min.js on initializing using internet explorer:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '_observe'
```

I think obviously that the problem is not in the server page because it have neither tryed to connect to the server when I got this error.
Thank you all.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: In my case, I forgot the 'new' keyword before kendo.data.DataSource to instanciate it.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I had done. I'm glad I am not the only one...

Comment: Yes, I've not write it before because I little bit ashamed of this!

Comment: I felt silly once I realized it as well. You should post it as the answer, though. If two of us did this you know there are many more who have done it as well.